# sql cast from varchar to double and save on duplicate key case

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, key, varchar

I'm using the following query in order to save some informations

```
INSERT INTO table (name,color,value) VALUES ('john','green','0,98')
```

All fields have type varchar
and in case of duplicate key (lets say john is the key) my query should change to

```
INSERT INTO table (name,color,value) VALUES ('john','green','0,98')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=CAST(value as DECIMAL(??)) + ?? ;
```

in the second example I want the value to be value += (the value from the table) and save it as varchar but I don't know how I can configure that. google didn't help , I found some examples here but nothing worked as I want.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

What DBMS are you using?  Here's an UPSERT example for Postgres you can try:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name, color, value)
VALUES('john', 'green', CAST('0.98' AS DECIMAL(10,2)))
ON CONFLICT (name) DO UPDATE SET
value = mytable.value + CAST('0.98' AS DECIMAL(10,2))
;
```

Just replace the decimal precision with what you need and put in the correct PK field names.  I haven't tested it, so you may need to fix the syntax.  But it should give you an idea of how to structure your query.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I'm using MySQL.
This one is complicated because the values are not known in the query. I made them directly in order to take the idea. The query will be executed via java so the values will be set in preparedStatement but I think is more sql problem than java. 
also the last line you posted, shouldn't be different? I mean the value= is made as decimal? if yes the query will run even if the type of field is varchar?
again thank you!

Comment: Ah, I read your question wrong then.  It sounds like you're having an issue CASTing the VARCHAR to a DECIMAL, is that right?  Are you getting an error message?  What results are you seeing?

Comment: Yea, you helped me a lot and I solve it!!

INSERT INTO table (name, color, value) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=CAST(value as DECIMAL(10,2)) + VALUES(value)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO table (name, color, value)
    VALUES ('john', 'green', '0,98')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = ( VALUES(value) + 0 )+ value;
```

This works as follows:

- `VALUES(value)` is the value being passed in for the update.
- `+ 0` does implicit conversion to a number.
- `+ value` increments the existing value.

MySQL will convert this back into a string.  However, I strongly advise you not to store numbers as strings.  SQL has proper data types for storing values.  Use them.